# How to store information from Facebook SDK login

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have attempted to implement the Facebook Javascript SDK login into my website but need to store information about the user so that when the user logs back in using Facebook I have information stored about them such as their previous in-website activities. Could I integrate this into a MySQL database?

Answer (score 3):

I think you may searching for the following way of storing logged user information into mysql database,

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     var fbname=response.name;
     var fbid=response.id;
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: page_for_storing_information,
     data: "name="+fbname+"&uid="+fbid,
         success: function(msg){ 
          }
         });
    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
   });
  } else {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
});
```